# ios localization for all countries/languages?

Tags: ios, iphone, localization, app-store

I'd like to deploy an app into the App Store (IOS only) and want the app to be available worldwide. 
Is there a rule that I must provide translations for each language of the specific country or would it be ok to translate the app into the most used languages and have a fallback to english if the actual language on the device is not supported?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a new iOS project you have the default language, after that you can add the languages you want. You can have an app that only have portuguese language and it will be available worldwide. The languages you support doesnt define the places where the app will be available. To define the places where the app will be available is in the developer portal where you configure the app description, price...